# Python Multiprocessing: Errors from different codes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a dataframe with 10 million rows. It takes too much time for iteration and calculation of each rows. I would like to get results in a shorter period. I tried different multiprocessing codes, but each time I faced different errors. Can someone helps me about this. Thank you advance.

d3 is the dataframe with more than 10 millions rows and 29 columns. The last columns' name is "Calculation", all values in this column is zero. By using the values of other columns, I calculated new values and I set new values to the "Calculation" column's each row.

## First code

```
def fun():
   for i in d3.index:
        if (d3.iloc[i, 3:4])[0] == (d3.iloc[i + 1, 3:4])[0]:
            d3.loc[d3.index[i], 'Calculation']==(d3.iloc[i, 22:23] - d3.iloc[i + 1, 22:23])
        else:
            d3.loc[d3.index[i],'Calculation']=d3.iloc[i, 13:14][0]

if __name__=="__main__":
    p1 = mp.Process(target=fun, args=())
    p2 = mp.Process(target=fun, args=())
    p3 = mp.Process(target=fun, args=())
    p4 = mp.Process(target=fun, args=())
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
```

## Second code

```
def fun(i):
    if (d3.iloc[i, 3:4])[0] == (d3.iloc[i + 1, 3:4])[0]:
       d3.set_value(i, "Calculation", (d3.iloc[i, 22:23] - d3.iloc[i + 1, 22:23]))
    else:
       d3.set_value(i, "Calculation", d3.iloc[i, 13:14])

if __name__=="__main__":
    p1 = mp.Process(target=fun, args=(d3.index, ))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=fun, args=(d3.index, ))
    p3 = mp.Process(target=fun, args=(d3.index, ))
    p4 = mp.Process(target=fun, args=(d3.index, ))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
```

## Third Code

```
def fun(q):

    for i in d3.index:
        if (d3.iloc[i, 3:4])[0] == (d3.iloc[i + 1, 3:4])[0]:
           d3.loc[d3.index[i], 'Calculation']==(d3.iloc[i, 22:23] - d3.iloc[i + 1, 22:23])
        else:
            d3.loc[d3.index[i], 'Calculation']==(d3.iloc[i, 22:23] - d3.iloc[i + 1, 22:23])
    q.put(d3)``

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = mp.Queue()
    processes = [mp.Process(target=fun, args=(q,)) for x in range(4)]
    for p in processes:
       p.start()
    for p in processes:
       p.join()
    results = [q.get() for p in processes]
```

Error1:

```
File "pandas\_libs\ops.pyx", line 103, in pandas._libs.ops.vec_compare
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)
```

Error2:

```
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in     pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

Error3:

```
File "pandas\_libs\ops.pyx", line 103, in pandas._libs.ops.vec_compare
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your third example, you need to pass both q and d3 to your sub-processes. What happens being the scene is that if **fun(q, d3)** modifies d3, then d3 in copied into the memory space dedicated to the sub-process that is running **fun(q, d3)** before being modified. If d3 is not modified in the sub-process, only a reference to d3 from the parent process is kept by the sub-process (which is efficient).

Now If d3 is very large and you want to reduce your running time and memory requirement, I would only pass a reference to d3 to your 4 sub-processes (i.e. just don't modify d3 in your sub-processes to avoid a copy), along with a start and stop row index. Then **fun(d3, q, start_idx, stop_idx)** would just return a list of length **stop_idx - start_idx** that your parent process would later put back into the original d3 column called **Calculation**.